# No WiFi Adapter Found on HP Probook

Tags: 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu on my HP Probook 430 and quickly found out I had no way of wirelessly connecting to the internet. How do I fix this?[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily connect to Internet and run in a terminal

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Disable Secure Boot if you are using UEFI.